# How to preg_match these HTML tags?

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this HTML file `items.php`:

```
<all>
  <designItems base="http://website.com/cms/items/">
    <item price="20" contentId="10928" name="Designed by X091">
      <hair set="10">
        <data>
          <![CDATA[
          [{"c":110092,"y":10,"x":34}]
          ]]>
        </data>
      </hair>
    </item>

    <item price="90" contentId="10228" name="Designed by XXX">
      <hair set="2">
        <data>
          <![CDATA[
          [{"c":110022,"y":-2,"x":90}]
          ]]>
        </data>
      </hair>
    </item>
  </designItems>
</all>
```

In `displayItems.php`, I would like to use `preg_match` to find the item(s) that has/have the `name="Designed by X091"` and get it's price and contentId, and its hair set and the data.

With preg_match is it possible? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, it's possible. What have you tried, so far?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson I wasn't sure where to start. All answers about `preg_match` searching for HTML have specific HTML attributes but mine's price and contentId attributes are different every time

Comment: This doesn't actually look like HTML, but rather like XML. Use PHP's XML-functions to read the attributes, instead of using `preg_match()`. Read about SimpleXML here: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you do not want to use regular expressions, as the potential for erroneous parsing is too great. Instead you should use parsing library, like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or similar.

Then you can use a simple loop, to check for the name attribute. Something like this, in other words:

```
$items = new SimpleXMLElement ($items);

// Loop through all of the elements, storing the ones we want in an array.
$wanted = array ();
foreach ($items->designItems->item as $current) {
    // Skip the ones we're not interested in.
    if ($current['title'] != 'designed by aaaa') {
        continue;
    }

    // Do whatever you want with the item here.
}
```